# Fallback Value at Object Declaration

Tags: typescript

Ok so I could not find anything about this. I hope it's not the most basic question ever.

In Typescript, suppose I want to create an instance of an object and make one parameter dependant on whether or not another object has got a parameter.

Example:

```
bigNote : BigNote = {
    title: 'Heads up!', 
    message: 'I like notes!', 
    color: 'red'
};
```

This is my first object. My second object would be:

```
smallNote: SmallNote = {
    title: bigNote.title, 
    message: bigNote.message
};
```

Now my question: bigNote may not have a title - if it doesn't - smallNote is supposed to get a replacement (some string), however if it does, I want it to be the bigNote.title.

I know how to do this with a subsequent if-clause but I wonder if this is possible to achieve in the initial declaration already?

(Hope this question isn't too confusing.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the logical OR operator. It evaluates to its second argument if its first is falsey:

```
title: bigNote.title || someString,
```

Where `someString` is the title you want to default to.

This is basically what you'd be doing with an `if` statement, but is instead a nice, inline expression.